# Splitting XML file into multiple at given tags ex: tags using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

Hi am having one big xml file, here i wanted split that xml file into multiple files based on the id(here id is unique). present am having xml file with 3 unique tag ids, I want to split them.

my file is as below

**main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tal xmlns="http://hello.com" schemaVersion="5.0.0" refSchemaFile="tal.xsd" status="Executable">
    <ExecProperties supportsParallelMostFlash="false"/>
    <talLine id="tl_1" status="Executable" baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60">
        <blFlash status="Executable">
            <blFlashTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>BTLD</processClass>
                    <id>00007732</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </blFlashTA>
            <blFlashTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>FLSL</processClass>
                    <id>00007735</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </blFlashTA>
        </blFlash>
    </talLine>
    <talLine id="tl_2" status="Executable" baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60">
        <swDeploy status="Executable">
            <swDeployTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>SWFL</processClass>
                    <id>00007736</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </swDeployTA>
            <swDeployTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>SWFL</processClass>
                    <id>00007bfc</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </swDeployTA>
        </swDeploy>
    </talLine>
    <talLine id="tl_3" status="Executable" baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60">
        <cdDeploy status="Executable">
            <cdDeployTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>CAFD</processClass>
                    <id>00006d4e</id>
                    <mainVersion>0</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>4</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </cdDeployTA>
        </cdDeploy>
    </talLine>
    <executionTime actualEndTime="0" actualStartTime="0" plannedEndTime="0" plannedStartTime="0"/>
    <installedECUList_Ist/>
    <installedECUList_Soll/>
</tal>
```

I need every "id"-data in a single file with header and footer(you can observe the below files), above is the example file. I need a spitted files like below

**1.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tal xmlns="http://hello.com" schemaVersion="5.0.0" refSchemaFile="tal.xsd" status="Executable">
    <ExecProperties supportsParallelMostFlash="false"/>
    <talLine id="tl_1" status="Executable" baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60">
        <blFlash status="Executable">
            <blFlashTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>BTLD</processClass>
                    <id>00007732</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </blFlashTA>
            <blFlashTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>FLSL</processClass>
                    <id>00007735</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </blFlashTA>
        </blFlash>
    </talLine>
    <executionTime actualEndTime="0" actualStartTime="0" plannedEndTime="0" plannedStartTime="0"/>
    <installedECUList_Ist/>
    <installedECUList_Soll/>
</tal>
```

**2.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tal xmlns="http://hello.com" schemaVersion="5.0.0" refSchemaFile="tal.xsd" status="Executable">
    <ExecProperties supportsParallelMostFlash="false"/>
    <talLine id="tl_3" status="Executable" baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60">
        <cdDeploy status="Executable">
            <cdDeployTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>CAFD</processClass>
                    <id>00006d4e</id>
                    <mainVersion>0</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>4</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </cdDeployTA>
        </cdDeploy>
    </talLine>
    <executionTime actualEndTime="0" actualStartTime="0" plannedEndTime="0" plannedStartTime="0"/>
    <installedECUList_Ist/>
    <installedECUList_Soll/>
</tal>
```

**3.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tal xmlns="http://hello.com" schemaVersion="5.0.0" refSchemaFile="tal.xsd" status="Executable">
    <ExecProperties supportsParallelMostFlash="false"/>
    <talLine id="tl_2" status="Executable" baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60">
        <swDeploy status="Executable">
            <swDeployTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>SWFL</processClass>
                    <id>00007736</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </swDeployTA>
            <swDeployTA status="Executable">
                <sgbmid>
                    <processClass>SWFL</processClass>
                    <id>00007bfc</id>
                    <mainVersion>2</mainVersion>
                    <subVersion>3</subVersion>
                    <patchVersion>11</patchVersion>
                </sgbmid>
            </swDeployTA>
        </swDeploy>
    </talLine>
    <executionTime actualEndTime="0" actualStartTime="0" plannedEndTime="0" plannedStartTime="0"/>
    <installedECUList_Ist/>
    <installedECUList_Soll/>
</tal>
```

I tried to remove some particular tag data with id, but no luck. can you please suggest me better ways to achieve my goal.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('main.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
mydata = root.find(".talLine[@id='tl_1']")
mydata.remove(mydata)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can tseem to see your code showing what you tried or a question about your code saying what didnt work

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle im very new to python, even I dont how to proceed.

Comment: Then Stack overflow is not the site you are looking for. this is not a tutorial or ask a question expect someone to write code for you site. there are many sites out there that will teach you how to parse xml with python

Comment: Hi @ChrisDoyle, i've tried something can you please check it once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to find out the Index of your tag(s) from root and clear them and save into new xml file

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
mytree=ET.parse('D://talfiles//TAL_High_Hud_Dcs_002_003_011.xml')
myroot=mytree.getroot()
myroot[1].clear()
myroot[2].clear()
mytree.write('D://talfiles//1.xml')
```

then your output will be saved into new file

1.xml file

```
<ns0:tal xmlns:ns0="http:hello.com" refSchemaFile="tal.xsd" schemaVersion="5.0.0" status="Executable">
<ns0:ExecProperties supportsParallelMostFlash="false" />
<ns0:talLine /><ns0:talLine /><ns0:talLine baseVariant="DKOMBI8" diagAddress="60" id="tl_3" status="Executable">
    <ns0:cdDeploy status="Executable">
        <ns0:cdDeployTA status="Executable">
            <ns0:sgbmid>
                <ns0:processClass>CAFD</ns0:processClass>
                <ns0:id>00006d4e</ns0:id>
                <ns0:mainVersion>0</ns0:mainVersion>
                <ns0:subVersion>4</ns0:subVersion>
                <ns0:patchVersion>11</ns0:patchVersion>
            </ns0:sgbmid>
        </ns0:cdDeployTA>
    </ns0:cdDeploy>
</ns0:talLine>
<ns0:executionTime actualEndTime="0" actualStartTime="0" plannedEndTime="0" plannedStartTime="0" />
<ns0:installedECUList_Ist />
<ns0:installedECUList_Soll />
```

But here we have challenge that we need to avoid the ns0 string in each line of output xml file